# How to reference the key from json with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How would I access the following json data

```
"users":{
    "2211392761":{"username":"user1"},
    "14300995184":{"username":"user2"},
    "2781554712":{"username":"user3"},
    "3554341":{"username":"user4"},
    "202611":{"username":"user5"},
    "17754300653761":{"username":"user6"}
}
```

I have this so far and I am aware it is completely wrong:

````
Object.keys(jsonevents["events"]).forEach(function(key) {
    if(eventName == jsonevents["events"][key]["name"]){
        if(jsonevents["events"][key]["users"]){
            if(jsonevents['events'][key]["users"][message.author.id]){
                delete jsonevents['events'][key]["users"][message.author.id];
                fs.writeFile(eventsjson, JSON.stringify(jsonevents),'utf8');
                sayMessage += "```User is no longer part of the event "+jsonevents['events'][key]["name"]+"```";
            } else {
                sayMessage += "```user is not in the event "+jsonevents['events'][key]["name"]+"```";
            }
        } else {
            sayMessage += "```Why do we have no users```";
        }
    } else {
        //sayMessage += "```No event found```";
    }
});
````

I need to be able to access the key by passing in the username, so `user2` would give me `14300995184` so i can then use this to remove the user from the event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search through the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with `find()` and return the right object. It will return an array of `key/value` the key will be what you're after:

```js
let users = {
    "2211392761":{"username":"user1"},
    "14300995184":{"username":"user2"},
    "2781554712":{"username":"user3"},
    "3554341":{"username":"user4"},
    "202611":{"username":"user5"},
    "17754300653761":{"username":"user6"}
}

let found = Object.entries(users).find(([key, value]) => value.username === "user2")
console.log(found && found[0]) // found is undefined if not found
```

Comment: ooh, object.entries - i like that, thank you i will try it out

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the `entries` (key-value pairs) of the `users` object, and use `.find` to find the username that matches the one you're trying to find. The first item in the entry (the key) will be what you're looking for:

```js
const obj = {
  "users": {
    "2211392761": {
      "username": "user1"
    },
    "14300995184": {
      "username": "user2"
    },
    "2781554712": {
      "username": "user3"
    },
    "3554341": {
      "username": "user4"
    },
    "202611": {
      "username": "user5"
    },
    "17754300653761": {
      "username": "user6"
    }
  }
}
const findEntry = usernameToFind => {
  const foundEntry = Object.entries(obj.users)
    .find(([, { username }]) => username === usernameToFind);
  if (foundEntry) return foundEntry[0];
};
console.log(findEntry('user5'));
console.log(findEntry('userthatdoesntexist'));
```